# Combining SUMIF() and SUBTOTAL() for Dynamic Subtotal

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need help combining two formulas.

What I need is to subtotal a range based on a criteria and I need that subtotal to change when the range is filtered.

I have two formulas that work separately. Any help in combining them would be greatly appreciated (I have looked at other posts for hours and cannot work it out!)

```
 =SUBTOTAL(9,AW5:AW552)  
 =SUMIF(AV$5:AW$552,AV558,AW$5:AW$552)
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't understand, the sumif does what the subtotal does, but how you want it. Or maybe just use a [sumproduct](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumproduct-HP005209293.aspx)?

Comment: The `SUMIF()` sums a range based on a criteria, while the `SUBTOTAL()` sums the results of the `SUMIF()`. The idea is that once you filter the rows, the `SUBTOTAL()` will sum only rows that are still showing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't put in the absolute references, but this should work. If it's not perfect, I don't understand your `sumif` going across columns is all.

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(AW5,ROW(AW5:AW552)-ROW(AW5),,1)),--(AV5:AV552=AV558))`

Comment: A comment why this works or what this solution consits of would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can can use subtotal like this

total =subtotal(109,B5:B10)   **Multiple total formulas can be used**

grandtotal =sumifs(B:B,A:A,"total") **which only pulls rows labeled "total"**

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based on multiple columns, so filter based on 'AV' column values and calculated SUBTOTAL. Of course this is a manual method.