# Understanding SumIF and Subtotal combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've come across this solution to combining sumif and subtotal formula but I don't understand it..

[Combining SUMIF() and SUBTOTAL() for Dynamic Subtotal](https://superuser.com/questions/709709/combining-sumif-and-subtotal-for-dynamic-subtotal)

Could anyone please offer an explanation of the the way this set of functions works together so that it can be understood by other inexperienced users (like me)? This solution obviously solves the question but is very difficult to adapt for a different dataset, without some more insight. (I'd rather not post my own specific question because if I did, the next person with this query will have the same problem!)

Thanks!

Comment: Without your data, how would we answer the question for you?

Comment: The point is, if you can explain how the formula works by breaking down the calculation, then all I need to do is adjust the references. I already have the solution (I know that this is the right one because I've seen it on several sites), I just don't understand how to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(AW5,ROW(AW5:AW552)-ROW(AW5),,1)),--(AV5:AV552=AV558))
```

`Sumproduct` - multiplies one array by another and adds them together.

`Subtotal` - gives you the subtotal of a specific operation on a range(s) - [here are the arguments](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx). 109 = sum

`Offset` - takes the reference and uses offset to reference a cell that is offset from it.

`row` - gives you the row number of the reference

The `--` notation essentially forces [true] and [false] to return as [1] and [0] for the array. When you operate on true or false, they become numerical, so here you are operating and then reversing the sign. You could instead `*1`

---

So, if I'm reading this correctly:

- Row-Row returns an array of numbers that are offset from AW5 by a
  height of 1
- Check AV5:AV552 for matching AV558, as an array of 0 and 1
- Sum the first array and multiply it by the second array.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Ray, that's a massive help. I understood what results I could expect from a SUMPRODUCT but not how the calculation worked so we're getting there. The part of the formula that's still confusing me is the OFFSET - could you please explain it's purpose within this particular formula? Or to put the question another way, what would happen if it wasn't used and a manually selected reference was used instead?

Comment: @AlexS the offset works as the countif, so if the offset works, then do the sum. So if you don't offset, and use a reference, it won't adjust as the array is processed.

Comment: Got it so my formula would be `=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET($AF$6,ROW($AF$6:$AF$91)-ROW($B$6),,1)),--($B$6:$B$91=$B$95))` if I want to calculate the sum of visible (not filtered) values in the cells AF6:AF91, as long as the value in the corresponding row within the range B6:B91 matches B95. Does that look right?

Comment: @AlexS no, the first `$B$6` should be `AF6`

Comment: thanks, it seems to work with the original reference but I can see why your suggestion is best practice. That's solved my query.